# How can I solve average problem in mapreduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have learned Mapreduce. However, I don't understand this Mapreduce average problem.

1. Scenario 1: I want to average 1 to 10 by Mapreduce. So, I split three maps below.

   A. map 1: 1, 2, 3 / average: 2

   B. map 2: 4, 5, 6 / average: 5

   C. map 3: 7, 8, 9, 10 / average: 8.5

   then I take average 2, 5, 8.5
   so average(1-10) is 5.17.
2. Scenario 2: And I split another three maps below.

   A. map 1: 1, 2, 3  / average: 2

   B. map 2: 4, 5, 6, 7  / average: 5.5

   C. map 3: 8, 9, 10  / average: 9

   then I take average 2, 5.5, 9
   so average(1-10) is 5.5
3. I want 5.5 (Correct answer) in Scenario 1. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your map output wouldn't be an average. It should be a sum of all the numbers.

Then you force all mappers to a single reducer, then sum all the sums, and then divide to get the average